# WCF: The incoming message was signed with a token which was different fron what used to encrypt the body. This was not expected

Tags: wcf, security, web-services, token

For what ever reason, a critical third peaty webservice functions like this. I can connect, send a request, and receive valid response, but i still get the error message. This only happens on one server.

"The incoming message was signed with a token which was different fron what used to encrypt the body. This was not expected." (sic)

This only happens on one server, but it's critical that I get the data. I don't have control over the server and while I'm aware what the message means, frankly I don't care. It's their call how they configure their own servers and send back the proper information. All I want is the data.

Is there any "shut up and deal with it" security setting in WCF so I can get data properly from the server?

Comment: Silly server. Of course different keys are used for signing and encryption... that's just good security. What, they didn't expect good security? Maybe it's possible for you to downgrade your client to a single certificate when accessing that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to open up a trouble ticket with Microsoft to solve this. Those guys are good and it raised up pretty high up the chain.

In the end it was something simple - the certificate on my machine was somehow corrupt. I had delete it and reinstall it then everything magically began to work.

Comment: @TomKerkhove : That was the problem in my case. I'm guessing there are multiple problems that all result in this error message

Answer (score 1):

What kind of tokens are you using? Certificates? If so, this article might be useful: "[How to: use different X509 Certificates for signing and encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729856.aspx)". In particular, look at the part that reads "To use multiple certificates on the client".